# how to use flock to orchestrate running of different programs, so that they can run at different time?

Tags: linux, bash, flock

in a remote host, I want to run 3 programs A , B and C but I want them to run at different time so if A is running, B and C can't run
so when I want to run A, if I detect that the file is locked I wait until it is unlocked

my idea is to create a lock file among these programs like mutex lock between processes
like:

if file is unlocked; then
 lock file
./programA
 unlock file
 fi

someone told me `flock` can be used for this purpose
I searched on google
the code is like:
(
flock -s 200
./program
) 200>/var/lock/mylockfile

but I don't know how to make it as a shell script
I make shell script trylock.sh like

```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e

    (
    flock -x -w 10 200
    sleep 20
    ) 200 > lockfile
```

when I run it, I got

```
trylock.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `200'
```

Besides, how to set the lock timeout to be intinite

can anyone give some example scripts?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra space between `200` and `>`, use `200>` in the redirect.

That 200 is file number, and `200>` redirects that, while `200 >` is nonsense, hence the syntax error.

For reference: [man page of `flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock).

Comment: Just leave out the timeout (according to the man page I linked to), in your code that is `-w 10` part.

Comment: what is the meaning of file number? is it socket number? thanks

Comment: @misteryes I think the official name is "file descriptor", the number returned by many different system calls, such as `open()` and `socket()`. So yeah, socket is one type of file descriptor.